# pick a random element from an array, repeat until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, fixed

I have the following issue: I have a fixed 
sum [30] and array of numbers. My questions is how do I subtract random numbers of num from sum until i get the rest number >1, <2 like 1.09 or 1.05?

```
var num= [0.99, 1.99, 2.99, 3.99, 4.99, 5.99, 6.99, 7.99, 8.99, 9.99];
var sum= [30];
```

---

### console.log()

```
[30]

[0.99,
1.99,
0.99,
4.99,
6.99,
1.99,
2.99,
4.99
2.99]

[1.09]
```

---

### console.log(again)

[30]

```
[7.99,
6.99,
4.99,
6.99,
1.99,

[1.05]
```

Comment: Its very unclear here ,please elaborate more what you are looking for

Comment: If you take random number from your array, you can easily encouter this problem: 30 - (9.99 + 7.99 + 5.99 + 8.99) with give a negative number, because the last random item from num was unfortunately too big. That's not clear.

Comment: So just to clarify, you have a certain number "sum" (in the example it's 30) and you have an array of other numbers "num" (in the example [0.99, 1.99, 2.99, 3.99, 4.99, 5.99, 6.99, 7.99, 8.99, 9.99]). You want to keep subtracting a random "num" from the "sum" until you have a subtracted value that is between 1 and 2? What should happened if the subtraction goes under 1?

Comment: @allu obviously - try again. the user did say 'until' between 1 and 2

Comment: @Smytt No, allu is right. What happen if the random number make the "sum" goes under 1 ?. The question definitely not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function expects you to give it a target sum (as a number, not array with 1 element), the array of possible subtraction values and a target array of 2 elements - min and max.

```js
var num = [0.99, 1.99, 2.99, 3.99, 4.99, 5.99, 6.99, 7.99, 8.99, 9.99];
var sum = 30;
var target = [1, 2];

function subtract(sum, num, target) {

  // pick a random index of whatever array is provided.
  const randomIndex = Math.round((num.length - 1) * Math.random());

  // * 100 / 100 is to successfully round to the 2nd decimal place.
  const newSum = Math.round((sum - num[randomIndex]) * 100) / 100;

  if (newSum >= target[1]) {
    console.log(`Subtracted ${num[randomIndex]}. Result is ${newSum}.`);
    subtract(newSum, num, target);
  }
  else if (newSum > target[0] && newSum <= target[1]) {
    console.log(`Subtracted ${num[randomIndex]}. Result is ${newSum}. Done.`);
  }
  else {
    console.log(`Couldn't subtract ${num[randomIndex]}. Result is ${sum}.`);
    subtract(sum, num, target);
  }
}

subtract(sum, num, target);
```

Comment: basically - get a random index to pick a subtraction value from the array. Try to subtract it. If the results is more than 2 - success. invoke the function again with the new sum. If the result is below the minimum - fail. Try again with a new random index. If the result is between min and max - success! the subtraction is now finished.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering in person, this was exactly the advice I needed.

Comment: @BFM happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **0/1** *knapsack* dynamic programming here. It is standard knapsack problem.

Suppose, you are trying in first number. You may either subtract this number from sum or ignore this number. So you will try all possibilities. This kind of **taking/non-taking** is called **0/1** knapsack.

You can learn **0/1** knapsack from this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/